# IIS Session hangs - How to resolve "website leaking resources to the finalizers"?

Tags: c#, iis, session, freeze

I am experiencing the exact same issue as a user reports on eggheadcafe, but don't know what steps to take after reading the following answer.:

> Two problems you should chase down:
>   1. Why is the website leaking resources to the finalizers. That is
>   bad
>   2. What is Oracle code waiting on -- work with Oracle's support on it

This is the issue:

> I have an intermittent problem with a
>   web site hosted on IIS6 (w2k3 sp2).
>
> I appears to occur randomly to users
>   when they click on a hyperlink within
>   a page.   The request is sent to the
>   web server but a response is never
>   returned.  If the user tries to
>   navigate to another hyperlink they are
>   not able to (i.e. the web site appears
>   to hang for that user).   Other users
>   of the website at the time are not
>   affected by this hang and if the user
>   with the problem opens a new http
>   session (closing IE and opening the
>   web site again) they no longer
>   experience the hang.
>
> I've placed a debugger (IISState) on
>   the w3wp process with the following
>   output.   Entries with "Thread is
>   waiting for a lock to be released. 
>   Looking for lock owner." look like
>   they might be causing the issue.   Can
>   anyone tell what lock the process is
>   waiting on?
>
> Thanks

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33799697/session-hangs.aspx

In my case my .Net C# MVC application runs against a MySQL database for data and a MS SQL database for .Net membership.

I hope someone with more knowledge of IIS can help resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a race condition in your database calls resulting in a deadlock at the database level. You may want to look at the settings you have in your application pool for database connections. Likely you will need to put some checks in somewhere or redefine procedures in order to reduce the likelihood of the race:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am now monitoring for deadlocks. The log hasn't reported any as of yet. I hope to get more results on monday when the application is in heavy use

Answer (score 0):

I would explain the experienced hang due to session serialization. Not the part about saving/loading it from some source, but that ASP.NET does not allow the same session to execute two parallel pages simultaneously, unless they execute with a readonly-session. The later is done either in the page directive, or in web.config, by setting [EnableSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate.aspx)="ReadOnly".

Your problem still exists, this wont change that the first thread hangs. I would verify that your database connections are disposed correctly. However, you never mention any Oracle database in your question (only Mysql and SQL Server). Why are you using the Oracle drivers at all? (This seems like a valid place to start debugging.)

However, as stated by David Wang in his answer in your linked question, part two of your problem is a lock that's never released. You'll need support from Oracle (or their source code) to debug this further.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear in my question. The problem description is similar to mine, in my case it is an C# MVC application running against MySQL and an SQL database. So I am not using Oracle :)


Thank you for your reply, changing sessionstate to read only would at least improve the user experience. 

I am also suspicious of this being somehow a network related issue. The user who reports most of the hangs is now connected to the production server through VPN so he uses the local IP adress. For the first time in weeks he reported a day without hangs. Is this explainable?

Answer (score 0):

IIS hang is not something surprising. IISState is out of date, and you may use Debug Diag,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919791 (if CPU usage is high)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919792 (otherwise)

The hang dumps should tell you what is the root cause.

Microsoft support can help analyze the dumps, if you are not familiar with the tricks. http://support.microsoft.com